How to detect if eyedropper has picked color outside the dom
I'm trying to modify eyedropper tool to make it pick color anywhere normally except for a specific div. I'm creating a 3d scene and I want to manually do raycast to pick actual color of material inside the scene in canvas (which is out of scope for this thread), so I need to know when eyedropper is dropped inside canvas.
Here is my dummy work so far. I was able to identify when eyedropper has picked inside canvas assuming user always picks inside the dom. But, what if the user clicks outside the dom? How do I detect outside color-pick?
I thought about using timeout to cancel mouseover event listener and conclude that it is outside div, but it might be too hacky.
Here is my work so far. Your help would be much appreciated. I thought about this for a while now.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Work for eyedropper</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button
        onclick="
            console.log('Open eyedropper now');

            const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

            const eyeDropper = new EyeDropper();

            eyeDropper
                .open()
                .then(res => {
                    function onMouseOver (e) {
                        const { clientX: x, clientY: y } = e;
                        const elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

                                    if (elementMouseIsOver === canvas) console.log('---> Inside Canvas <---');
                                    else console.log('---> Outside canvas <---')
                                    window.removeEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
                                }

                    
                    window.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                                console.log('Eyedropper closed: ', e);
                        })
            
        "
    >Open eyedropper</button>

    <div id="canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;background: #eeeeff">
        <h1>Eyedropper should close when entering here</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

